# How do I copy image in OpenStack under a second name

Tags: openstack

Say I have an image named `org-image-name`, I want to create a new image that will be identical but have a different name (say `new-image-name`). How can I do it using CLI? Or maybe there is an aliases feature?

Comment: Barring other solutions you can download the image (`openstack image save ...`) and then upload it using a new name (`openstack image create ...`).

Comment: @larsks, yeah, thanks! I hoped there is a better way though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to directly clone an image. You could create a volume from the image and then create another image from that volume.

```
openstack volume create --image myimage tempvol
openstack image create --volume tempvol cloned-image
openstack volume delete tempvol
```

The speed however depends on your storage backend. With the proper backend (for example ceph) and the proper hardware the create operations should be nearly instantaneous.

Answer (score 2):

This worked in my test environment, too:

```
root@control01:~# openstack image save <IMAGE> | openstack image create --public <NEW_IMAGE>
```

If you don't specifiy a file name to the "save" command it goes to stdout, which you can read from in the image create command.
Because it's quite an important remark, I'll add Gerald's comment to the answer:

> Note that this will literally download and reupload the image to and
> from the machine where you are running this command on. Depending on
> the connection between the machine and the OpenStack API server and
> the size of the image this might not be desirable.

Comment: Note that this will literally download and reupload the image to and from the machine where you are running this command on. Depending on the connection between the machine and the OpenStack API server and the size of the image this might not be desirable.